# Generate NSDate from day, month, and year

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdate

I'm trying to generate a NSDate from a month day and year (all in integer format).

Right now my attempt is such:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSNumber *day = [dataSource valueForKey:@"day"];
NSNumber *month = [dataSource valueForKey:@"month"];
NSNumber *year = [dataSource valueForKey:@"year"];
[components setDay:[day intValue]];
[components setMonth:[month intValue]];
[components setMonth:[year intValue]];
NSDate *_date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

However, **_date** outputs the following when day = 24, month = 8, year = 2011:

> 0168-07-25 04:56:02 +0000

I must be doing something horribly wrong, but I have no idea what. Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Came here at the end of 2016 and this question is still helpful. Given that there are 30 helpful votes on this, I would vote to re-open if possible. Additionally, none of the close voters have objective-c, iOS, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdate in their top tags looking at their profiles.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have a typo in your code: (last line should be `setYear:`)

```
 [components setDay:[day intValue]];
 [components setMonth:[month intValue]];
 [components setYear:[year intValue]];
```

Comment: Yep, when you divide things out it ALMOST works out -- Not clear why the year is 168 vs 167, though, or why the day is 25 vs 24.  But the poor NSDateComponents object was no doubt sorely confused.

Comment: (The day is likely off due to a failure to set timeZone to GMT.)

Comment: Thanks! Definitely needed another set of eyes (or another pot of coffee):)

Comment: The date is off because things get weird when you use ancient years. There's been many subtle corrections throughout the use of calendars which have been accommodated for in Apple's framework. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtHist.html) if you're curious.

Answer (score 3):

One glaring glitch is:

```
[components setMonth:[year intValue]];    //setting month with year!
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling setMonth twice, the second time with the value for year. Should be:

```
[components setDay:[day intValue]];
[components setMonth:[month intValue]];
[components setYear:[year intValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo nowadays (2019) there is a more convenient syntax to access dictionary values with key subscription and properties with dot notation

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSNumber *day = dataSource[@"day"];
NSNumber *month = dataSource[@"month"];
NSNumber *year = dataSource[@"year"];
components.day = day.integerValue;
components.month = month.integerValue;
components.year = year.integerValue;
NSDate *_date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

and there is another API without date components

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSNumber *day = dataSource[@"day"];
NSNumber *month = dataSource[@"month"];
NSNumber *year = dataSource[@"year"];
NSDate *_date = [calendar dateWithEra:1 year:year.integerValue month:month.integerValue day:day.integerValue hour:0 minute:0 second:0 nanosecond:0];
```